# columnfamily_name still appears in system.schema_columns after delete

Tags: cassandra-2.0

i had a table named Customer.  i deleted it because now when i do desc or select on it i get an error.

problem is, it still shows up when i do:

```
cqlsh:showcase> select column_name, validator, type  from     system.schema_columns
 where columnfamily_name = 'Customer' allow filtering;

 column_name     | validator                                   | type
-----------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------
account_balance |  org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType |       regular
         age |   org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type |       regular
  first_name |    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type |       regular
   is_active | org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType |       regular
         key |    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType | partition_key
   last_name |    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type |       regular
  start_date |    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType |       regular

(7 rows)
```

How do I get rid of it?

```
drop table Customer
```

gives the error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured columnfamily customer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table identifier has uppercase, it needs to be quoted.

```
DROP TABLE "Customer";
```

Comment: i thought tables in cassandra had to be lowercase.  am i mistaken?

Comment: They are lowercase by default, but that is not a requirement: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#identifiers (see the bit about "quoted identifiers").